# CSS difference between ".cssClass object" and "object.cssClass"

Tags: html, css

I was doing some css today and was forced to change some syntax from:

`input.cssClass`

to

`.cssClass input`

How do these definitions differ, and when should we use either of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, that is an odd change. The first will collect all the `inputs` with class `cssClass`, while the second will take all `inputs` inside any element with `cssClass`.

```
<body>
 <input class="cssClass" type="text" />
 <div class="cssClass">
   <input type="text" />
 </div>
</body>
```

So here, the first input will be grabbed by your first selector, while the second input will be grabbed by your second selector. Neither selector will grab both.

Comment: change fixed it not my code I was fixing but i have done it before just wanted someone to confirm how it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

`input.cssClass` will apply that style to input type objects that have that class specified.

`.cssClass input` will apply that style to input type objects that are contained within any other object type that has the `cssClass` class.

Answer (score 2):

The first works with any `input` element that has the class `cssClass`:

```
<input class="cssClass" type="text" />
```

Whereas the second works with any `input` element inside an element with class `cssClass`, eg.:

```
<div class="cssClass">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```